# I receive blank page after i have deployed my app

Tags: typescript, express, heroku, tailwind-css, vite

I need help with my React app. After done with my application that was developed in React, I decided to use Vite inside due to performance issues.

All the integration works well in my local environment when I build and try with preview, but since deployed on Heroku I have a blank page, someone help me pls. This is my script on my `package.json`

Frontend:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "serve -s build",
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "tsc && vite build",
        "test": "vite test",
        "eject": "vite eject",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    }
```

Backend:

```
"scripts": {
        "data:import": "ts-node ./src/models/seeder.model.ts",
        "data:destroy": "ts-node src/models/seeder.model.ts -d",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node dist/server.js",
        "postinstall": "tsc ",
        "tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
        "watch-node": "nodemon dist/server.js",
        "server": "nodemon ./src/server.ts ",
        "client": "npm start --prefix fa-shop",
        "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
        "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku main",
        "heroku-postbuild": " npm install --prefix fa-shop && npm run build --prefix fa-shop",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client \" "
    }
```

And folder are organized like this

```
appBackend --
           -- node_modules/backend
           -- frondend
                      --- node_modules/frontend
```

Image from heroku [image: no error in the console - image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolve the issue, the problem was with the Cors policy (`cors()`) and Content Security Policy (CSP), I make some updates in my vite file too

```js
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: `https://fashopapp-c129f80f4143.herokuapp.com`,
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
    ws: true,
  },
},
hmr: { overlay: false }
```

And after in my server file by adding the cors package with this configuration

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'https://fashopapp-c129f80f4143.herokuapp.com/ ',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Authorization', 'Content-Type'],
    maxAge: 86400,
  })
)
```

and CSP

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    "style-src-elem 'self'"
  )
  next()
})
```

I think the can be helpful for someone.